# Nodemailer - Works locally but not on production

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/ba82f74071cc38a0700b

Before changing some settings, e.g. host and port, it was working fine locally, but just won't work on production.

Anyone know why?

Thanks

Comment: where is your application deployed...??

Answer (score 25):

Disable Captcha temporarily so you can mail using new server,

https://accounts.google.com/b/0/displayunlockcaptcha

Comment: Wow, This saved me from a lot of trouble

Comment: What the heck is this?? This save me too when deploying to heroku

Comment: How to disable with a different Google account? This automatically just leads to a page to disable for my main account

Comment: @Atenean1 open a browser in incognito mode, sign in with your secondary account (the one you cant to unlock) and then open the link from above.

Comment: What the !!! Solved my issue! I was stuck. Thanks a lot man!

Comment: Any update on this? That link looks broken now

Answer (score 2):

i think this is happening because of port number and your firewall at this port is not allowing you to send mail over this port(80) . try with 587 or 465 which are actually the standard port number for SMTP.

changed your code a bit

```
/**
 * Created by atul on 29/3/16.
 */

var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'Gmail',
  //host: 'myhost',
  port: 465,
  secure: true,
  auth: {
    user: 'mymail@gmail.com',
    pass: 'mypassword'
  }
});
  mailOptions = {
    from: 'mymail@gmail.com',
    to: 'mymail@gmail.com',
    subject: 'You received a new message at !',
    text: 'Hello Mailer',
html: ''
};
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
  if(error){
  console.log(error)
}else{
  console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response)
}
});
```

Comment: I use app.listen(80), that's not the one I use?

Comment: can you write your code that you are trying because from the above code i am just getting that you want to create a transport over port 80 which is wrong

Comment: just tried both 587 and 465, neither worked ._. the code is the same, just port: 587/465 rather than 80

Comment: have you checked that there is no firewall on these ports and also these ports are open?