# Why I can not send email from amazon AWS Lightsail?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, server, gmail, amazon-lightsail

When I was using amazon EC2 free instance, and in my Node API project, I used Nodemailer to sent emails from my GMAIL account, and that was running perfectly without any issue, but not I have moved on to the Amazon lightsail for production, with the same code I can not send email.

I have opened all the ports in lightsail which I had in EC2 instance.

I have tried all other possible ways but it isn't working. I am getting no errors.

This is my code to send email

```
const mailOptions = {
        from: email.from || emailSettings.auth.user,
        to: email.to,
        subject: email.subject,
        attachments: email.filePath,
        html: email.template
      };
```

Comment: We need a more complete description than *"it isn't working."*  What exactly happens?  An error?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot i am not getting any error.
What more information do you require?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution on this thread

[Nodemailer - Works locally but not on production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36280121/nodemailer-works-locally-but-not-on-production)

You have to change some of your gmail settings:

Disable Captcha temporarily so you can mail using new server,

https://accounts.google.com/b/0/displayunlockcaptcha